# Coffeescript if else doesnt work

Tags: coffeescript, grunt-contrib-coffee

I am using coffeescript with grunt and am trying to only include JS files file pattern "*.min.js". Somehow my test is failing though and all files get included. So my if statement always returns true. How do I make this work?

```
getJsDependencies = ->
  js_dependencies_path = path.join __dirname, "js", "dep"
  paths = []
  for js_file in fs.readdirSync(js_dependencies_path)
    file_path = path.join __dirname, "js", "dep", js_file
    console.log js_file
    if js_file.indexOf ".min.js", 0 > 0
      paths.push file_path
  paths
```

I tried all kinds of combinations of js_file.indexOf but I am not having any luck with having only .min.js files included. In fact, I want to exclude them but I am stuck with string matching not the logic.

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If we add the implicit function calling parentheses to

```
if js_file.indexOf ".min.js", 0 > 0
```

we get:

```
if js_file.indexOf(".min.js", 0 > 0)
```

so you're really passing `false` to `indexOf` as its second argument and that doesn't make a lot of sense.

I think you want to say this:

```
if js_file.indexOf(".min.js", 0) > 0
```

Or since the second argument to [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) is zero anyway:

```
if js_file.indexOf('.min.js') > 0
```

but even here you need the parentheses when calling `indexOf` to ensure that you're comparing the `indexOf` return value with zero.